# How to view website templates in a gallery?

Tags: wordpress, web

I have some website templates on my local machine and now I want this to look like a gallery page where I can see the screenshot of the website template ahead and click one button to see it in full view as well as click to go to the template itself. Can anybody tell me how can I achieve it? Is there any open source tool to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found one. Just pick up any e-commerce theme from WordPress and install the **woocommerce** plugin and add your templates as a product and set a permalink.